# Why is .on('load', function () { not working for a button?

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

**Working `.on('click'`**

There is no problem.

```
myApp.onPageAfterAnimation('about', function (page) {
$$('#button1').on('click', function () {
alert('test');
```

---

**Not Working `.on('load'`**

Why?

```
myApp.onPageAfterAnimation('about', function (page) {
$$('#button1').on('load', function () {
alert('test');
```

Comment: This is not jQuery.its framework7.

Comment: what's the `#button1` tag ?  i think there is no `onload` event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onload` event only supported HTML tags:

```
body, frame, iframe, img, input type="image", link, script, style
```

Comment: `document` as in `$$(document).on('load', function() {})` works too